# Is this a valid SQLite query

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have:

```
String sqlite = "SELECT count(_id) AS _lCount FROM answers WHERE phase = 3 and correct_incorrect='1'
```

as a query, but I need the correct_incorrect column to also take into account a "1*"

Would this be a valid way to account for it?

```
String sqlite = "SELECT count(_id) AS _lCount FROM answers WHERE phase = 3 and correct_incorrect='1'or'1*'
```

I would test it, but the possibility of a "1*" is rare and would take a few hours of testing. So I want to make sure I'm not just wasting my time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try it by using `IN`

```
String sqlite = "SELECT count(_id) AS _lCount FROM answers WHERE phase = 3 and correct_incorrect IN ('1','1*')"
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, It should be something like:

```
String sqlite = "SELECT count(_id) AS _lCount FROM answers WHERE phase = 3 and (correct_incorrect='1' or correct_incorrect = '1*')
```

Comment: Wouldn't SQL interpret that as: (phase = 3 and correct_incorrect='1') || (correct_incorrect = '1*')

Comment: Awesome. That makes sense. Appreciate the help, saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 1):

As many querys are given here but I think '1' would be comes in '1*'

```
String sqlite = "SELECT count(_id) AS _lCount FROM answers WHERE phase = 3 and correct_incorrect like '1*'";
```

what about this query?